# What would be the benefit of genAI cryptographic watermarking if the key is known only to OpenAI?

Tags: openai, watermarking

> So then to watermark, instead of selecting the next token randomly, the idea will be to select it pseudorandomly, using a cryptographic pseudorandom function, **whose key is known only to OpenAI**.
> <sub>Roger Montti, [How The ChatGPT Watermark Works And Why It Could Be Defeated](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/chatgpt-watermark/475366/), December 2022.  (emphasis added; this topic has also been in the news recently; see e.g. [this](https://www.reuters.com/technology/openai-google-others-pledge-watermark-ai-content-safety-white-house-2023-07-21/).)</sub>

Okay, but...

**Question**: What would be the benefit of genAI cryptographic watermarking if the key is known only to OpenAI?

I'm interpreting the above as implying that only OpenAI can detect OpenAI-generated content, which makes it not especially useful for plagiarism detection.  [Although I'm not precisely sure how the watermarking would be implemented; I guess it's possible the private key is used for watermarking, while a public key might be used for watermark-detection (somewhat like RSA cryptosystems).]

Maybe it could be used as a way for OpenAI to avoid training GPT on GPT-generated text, without giving the same advantage to its competitors.  That seems like a monopolistic tactic.

Answer (score 4):

The benefit would be that OpenAI (the company) could later detect if some generated text came from ChatGPT. You are correct in that the idea being proposed by Scott Anderson is that only OpenAI would be able to do the detection.

The article you linked has a lot of jumbled points and "explainers" that don't really seem to be on topic. It looks as if the article itself (or portions of it) were AI generated.

Instead, you can [read the full blog post](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=6823) by Scott Anderson (which is actually a transcript of a presentation he gave) for more information and context. The post is long, and the sections that are relevant to watermarking appear the "My Projects at OpenAI" header.

The blog post seems to imply that the main benefit of the watermark would be in a legal context where OpenAI is under a lawsuit or court order and needed to have some assurance that some text was or wasn't generated by ChatGPT

> Some might wonder: if OpenAI controls the server, then why go to all the trouble to watermark? Why not just store all of GPT’s outputs in a giant database, and then consult the database later if you want to know whether something came from GPT? Well, the latter could be done, and might even have to be done in high-stakes cases involving law enforcement or whatever. But it would raise some serious privacy concerns: how do you reveal whether GPT did or didn’t generate a given candidate text, without potentially revealing how other people have been using GPT? The database approach also has difficulties in distinguishing text that GPT uniquely generated, from text that it generated simply because it has very high probability (e.g., a list of the first hundred prime numbers)

OpenAI could potentially release a tool that would tell you if some provided text was generated by ChatGPT. Of course, this would likely accelerate the ability for counter-tools to sufficiently modify the text to remove or muddy the watermark.

Scott goes into a little more detail about the tool/counter-tool in the Q&A section. He notes that

> It’s especially challenging if you impose one or more of the following conditions:
>
> - The AI’s code and parameters should be public (in which case, people might easily be able to modify it to remove the watermarking).
> - The AI should have at least some ability to modify itself, and
> - The means of checking for the watermark should be public (in which case, again, the watermark might be easier to understand and remove).